# SSRS display a N/A if a item is NULL, else display it's contents

Tags: sql, reporting-services, null, reporting

I am trying to create a report that will display "N/A" if it returns null in the following screenshot:

[image]

Anywhere there is no Closer or Direct Number or Date, I want to display "N/A"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming your field name is SomeField, instead of `Fields!SomeField.value` try following expression

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!SomeField.value) or Fields!SomeField.value="","N/A",Fields!SomeField.value)
```